# Error while querying inherited class from telerik open access ORM

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-open-access

I am using latest version of **Telerik Open Access ORM** in my ASP.net  C# web application. 
In my **EntitiesModel1.rlinq** , I have  mapped a table named "**Customer** " from a database. Then I have created a domain class named "**SubCustomer**" and added anew property field named "**SubName** : **String**" into it. Then deleted default property filed from the domain class. Then I have applied **inheritance** for **Customer-SubCustomer** classes. So the inheritance arrow pointing from  **SubCustomer** to **Customer** entity now.

I have then applied **vertical** inheritance stuff to **SubCustomer** class and mapped "**SubName**" field with "**CustomerName**" field in **Customer** Class using "**Default** **mapping**". The Update from database model and validate all process have been completed successfully without having any error or warning.

While deploying  this context in my web application and querying like :

```
        using (EntitiesModel1 context = new EntitiesModel1())
        {             
            List<SubCustomer> lstCustomer = (from entity in context.SubCustomer
                                        select entity).ToList();
        }
```

I am getting an error:

***Error executing query: Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'SubCustomer.
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.PreparedStatementImp.executeQuery()
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.conn.PooledPreparedStatement.executeQuery()
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.fetch.FetchResultImp.Execute()
SQL:
SELECT a.[CustomerID] AS COL1, b.[voa_class] AS COL2, a.[SubName] AS COL3, b.***

I have tried to query "**Customer**" entity as well  but getting the same error.
Please help.

Regards,
Praveen.